# Syntax Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: json, jwt, local-storage, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error on JSON.parse

```
const userInfo =
    localStorage.getItem("user") !== "undefined"
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
      : localStorage.clear();
```

I set the user first in my login component:

```
const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    const anyUser =localStorage.setItem("user", decoded);
```

Here is my JSON content:

```
aud: "57**********-jc601taprt3p68jkkv6pig3ntqk19nt2.apps.googleusercontent.com"
​
azp: "57**********-jc601taprt3p68jkkv6pig3ntqk19nt2.apps.googleusercontent.com"
​
email: "user@gmail.com"
​
email_verified: true
​
exp: 16676*****
​
family_name: "John"
​
given_name: "Doe"
​
iat: 16676*****
​
iss: "https://accounts.google.com"
​
jti: "dbd78b14d4f87f1e32b0ecfc2f8076**********"
​
name: "John Doe"
​
nbf: 16676*****
​
picture: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ALm5wu1A2dnuB2PU3zd6Pcc52GGdTWw*****IcMahE_XXw=s96-c"
​
sub: "1167323005026********"
```

I used jwt_decode, The Login component has the setItem, while my Home component has the getItem

Comment: Clearly, the problem is with the JSON content, which you don't include in your question. It's pretty much impossible to answer a question about the JSON syntax without seeing the JSON.

Comment: The above is the JSON content

Comment: There is still no JSON content in your question. You need to [edit] to add it there, not dump it into a comment where it can't be seen.

Comment: Updated, you can check

Answer (score -1):

Edit: updated based on question update. The posted json is not valid. The keys need to be quoted and the values need commas - it needs to look something like the following:

```json
{
  "aud": "57**********-jc601taprt3p68jkkv6pig3ntqk19nt2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "azp": "57**********-jc601taprt3p68jkkv6pig3ntqk19nt2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "email": "user@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "exp": 1667600000,
  "family_name": "John",
  "given_name": "Doe",
  "iat": 1667600000,
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "jti": "dbd78b14d4f87f1e32b0ecfc2f8076**********",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "nbf": 166760000,
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ALm5wu1A2dnuB2PU3zd6Pcc52GGdTW,w*****IcMahE_XXw=s96-c",
  "sub": 11673230050260000
}
```

This is a great resource to help with json - it can be a little tricky but once you get it down, it starts making more sense.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

Try using this tool to adjust your json https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser

Comment: Here is the json content:

Comment: I would remove the personal information from this comment and make it generic "user@example.com", e.g.

Comment: Please see my updated answer above. The json from your previous comment was not valid json.